# How should i setup headers at server and client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-headers, basic-authentication

I have writed server with nodejs and added handler on path

```
// /api/friend/ 
router.get("/search/:userSearchParam" , async (req, res) => {
  let user = await User.find(
    { name: { $regex: req.params["userSearchParam"], $options: "i" } },
    { name: 1, _id: 1 }
  );

  if (user.length > 0) {
    res.json(user);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204); //json({"message": 'З даним іменем нікого немає'})
  }
});
```

and i add to it midlware as i findout at the Internet to allow CORS

```
 withAuth: function (req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Authorization, X-Custom-Header');
   
 /*    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", 'Authorization, Uid'); */
    next();
}
```

server is running on localhost

but when i try to load data from React (localhost:3000)

```
   handleChange(event) {
const val = event.target.value;
const auth = this.state.auth;
console.log(this.state.auth);
this.setState({
  [event.target.name]: val,
});

if (val.length > 3) {
  axios.get("http://localhost/api/friend/search/" + val, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': this.state.auth,
        'Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
      credentials: "include",
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      // alert(err.response.data.message);
    });
   }
 }
  render() {
```

and  i cannot get them because of
[image]

How should i setup headers at server and client?

Comment: also client does not send Authorization to server

Comment: `"http://localhost/api/friend/search/" + val` in your code should be `":3000/api/friend/search/" + val`, missing port and dont hardcode domain

Comment: i run node server on 80 port, and  my react app is on 3000 port, thats why itry to finda way to resolwe CORS, or maybe i did not understand something?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoSJ3bNGPp0

or use this middlware at server ( YEAA BOY)))))))))))))))))))))  (6h wasted:((  ))

```
router.use(    function (req, res, next){
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, 
Accept, Authorization");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true');

/*    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, 
 Accept, Authorization');
res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", 'Authorization, Uid');*/ 

  if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET')
return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});
```